# 'Select as' Select field but return different name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way of querying fields but using different names to reference them? I've got schemas like these:

```
{
  stats: {
    monday:{goals:10,tackles:20},
    tuesday:{goals:10,tackles:20}
  }
}
```

I need to get stats.monday or stats.whatever `as` just stats. So I can use stats.goals or stats.tackles. I can assign stats.monday to stats, but through Mongoose is there any way to `select as` like we do in mysql?

Comment: take a look at $project in aggregation framwork https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: I've checked it out, but I can't get how it's going to help me. Could you explain what it does?